# Question about Schrodinger equation in atomic units vs in SI units

Tags: schroedinger-equation, terminology, dimensional-analysis, si-units, unit-conversion

In SI units, we see that the Schrodinger equation can be written as
\begin{align}
i\hbar\partial_t \Psi= \left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}\Delta_x+V(x)\right)\Psi
\end{align}
whereas, in atomic units, we have
\begin{align}
i\partial_\tau \psi= \left(-\frac{1}{2}\Delta_X+\tilde V(X)\right)\psi.
\end{align}
Hence we have two sets of variables $(t, x)$ and $(\tau, X)$ (not conventional notation, but I can't think of better ones).

**My question is simply:** do people call $(t, x)$ the macroscopic variables and $(\tau, X)$ the microscopic variables in the physics literature? To me, one unit in $x$, i.e. $x\sim 1$, is much larger than $X\sim 1$. Likewise, $t$ is passing much more slowly than $\tau$.  However, it feels funny for me to call $(t, x)$ the macroscopic variables.

**Addition:** If people don't distinguish these variables as microscopic or macroscopic, then how should we refer to them?

Answer (score 1):

A quantity isn't bigger or smaller because of the units that you use. The values that the variables take will simply be different in scale.

Usually when variables are described as microscopic or macroscopic, they refer to whether the variables pertain to single atoms or the system as a whole, particularly in thermodynamics. For example, the spin of a specific particle is microscopic, but the magnetization of the entire sample is macroscopic. You wouldn't refer to $t$ or $\tau$  as microscopic or macroscopic simply because they tend to have very small or very large values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your comment. However, it seems like there are natural units for observing certain phenomena. For instance, if you want to describe the behavior of a single atom, looking at a scale of a one-meter box may be a bit much. Also, when you are trying to understand collective behaviors, then looking in a 1 unit atomic-scale box will probably lead to nothing.

Comment: Also, to observe the collective behavior of particles the time scale would also play a significant role. I don't think it is appropriate to observe the collective behavior of particles at a 1 unit atomic time scale.

Comment: I know natural macroscopic variables are like volumes, temperature, or pressure. The positions of individual particles are irrelevant. However, to observe the emergence of these macroscopic variables starting with a system of particles requires a natural scale. For me, I am trying to study the behavior of the classical limit of $\hbar\rightarrow 0$, so there is a distinction between $(\tau, X)$ and $(t, x)$, but I don't know what's the standard language people use.